# Counter example relating the ramification

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

I want to prove the following:

- If $K/F$ is unramified, then $LK/LF$ is unramified.

Let $f, K, L$ be number fields. Let $\mathfrak{p}$ be a prime in $F$, and $\mathfrak{P}$ a prime above $p$ in $LF$. If the following statement is true, then it is easy to conclude the above proposition.

- If $\mathfrak{p}$ is unramified in $K/F$, then $\mathfrak{P}$ is unramified in $LK/LF$.

Is it true? Or do we need a more suitable assumption on $F$ or $K$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The local version of this claim is Proposition 7.2 in Chapter II of Neukirch. To deduce the global version from the local version, just complete $ F, K, LF, LK $ at appropriate primes lying over $ \mathfrak p $ and verify the claim for each possible combination where the extension lattice is compatible with the lying over relations between the primes.

Comment: It seems that my question and the answer are very typical. That's why I feel that my problem is something more basic. I think I should ask it as an independent question, and then I will return back to this question. This is my new question https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3978580/basic-question-on-local-fields and I will return back to realize this question after that. Right now, I can not realize how your answer works.