# Basic question on local fields

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

Maybe my question is very easy and typical, but I have a serious problem with it. Actually it is not a single question, and it is a mix of probably simple questions. Let $K/\mathbb{Q}$ be a number field. Let $p$ be a rational prime number and suppose that $p\mathcal{O}_K=\mathfrak{p}_1^{e_1} \cdots \mathfrak{p}_g^{e_g}$. I know how to construct $K_{\mathfrak{p}_i}$. Are these pairwise nonisomorphic? If yes, then there a correspondence between the $\mathfrak{p}_i$'s, primes lying over $p$, and the local fields $K_{\mathfrak{p}_i}$'s. Do we have this factorization $p=\mathfrak{p}_1^{e_1}$ in $K_{\mathfrak{p}_i}/\mathbb{Q}_p$?

What is the best way to think about the corresponding valuations?

- I prefer to consider the $v_{\mathfrak{p}_i}$ as a map to $\dfrac{1}{e_i}\mathbb{Z}$, sending the uniformizers to $\dfrac{1}{e_i}$. If we consider that, then I think we have this relation $v_{\mathfrak{p}_i\big|\mathbb{Q}}(x)= v_p(x)$ for any $x \in \mathbb{Q}$.
- Also, we can consider the $v_{\mathfrak{p}_i}$ as a map to $\mathbb{Z}$, sending the uniformizers to $1$. If we consider that, then I think we have this relation $v_{\mathfrak{p}_i\big|\mathbb{Q}}(x)=e_i v_p(x)$ for any $x \in \mathbb{Q}$.

Which one is more standard and compatible? Which one do you suggest me to consider?

Edit: Also I have another question. Maybe I have to ask it as an independent question. Let $K/\mathbb{Q}_p$ be an extension of local fields. Then there is a unique prime $\mathfrak{p}$ in $K$. Corresponding to this prime we have the inertia degree $f$ and the ramification index $e$, and we have $p\mathcal{O}_{K}=\mathfrak{p}^e$ and $ef=[K:\mathbb{Q}_p]$. How can we find a global number field $L$, such that $L_v=K$ for some prime $v$ of $\mathcal{O}_L$?

Comment: If you mean pairwise non-isomorphic, the answer is no. For example, if $p$ splits completely in $K$ then every $K_{\mathfrak p_i}$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb Q_p$

Comment: Do we have the same for Galois extensions $K/\mathbb{Q}$? That for all $\mathfrak{p}_i$'s over $p$, all of $K_{\mathfrak{p}_i}$'s are isomorphic to each other?

Comment: The second answer by @reuns answers my question in the comments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Different completions may or may not be isomorphic.

In $\mathbf Q(i)$ we have $5=(1+2i)(1-2i)$ and both completions $\mathbf Q(i)_{(1+2i)}$ and $\mathbf Q(i)_{(1-2i)}$ are isomorphic to $\mathbf Q_5$.

In $\mathbf Q(\sqrt[3]{2})$ we have $(5) = \mathfrak p \mathfrak q$ where $\mathfrak p$ has norm 5 and $\mathfrak q$ has norm 25, so the completions of $\mathbf Q(\sqrt[3]{2})$ at these two primes do not have the same residue fields over $\mathbf F_5$ or in fact have the same degrees over $\mathbf Q_5$.

Concerning the different ways to normalize the discrete valuations, the two ways that you describe are the most commonly used. Neither is intrinsically better than the other, but if you want to treat $K$ as a field on its own (not as an extension of $\mathbf Q$) then it is common to normalize the different discrete valuations on $K$ to each have value group $\mathbf Z$.

The distinction between the two conventions you describe is related to whether you want to think of absolute values on an extension of local fields as an extension of functions, where the absolute value on the larger field restricts on the smaller field to the original absolute value used on the smaller field. If you want to get an absolute value on the algebraic closure of $\mathbf Q_p$ then you need to use absolute values on larger fields that are compatible with the ones already used on smaller fields.

Often an important condition to use that ties together all the absolute values on a number field is the product formula: $\prod_v |x|_v = 1$ for all $x$ in $K^\times$.

Comment: Also I have another question. Maybe I have to ask it as an independent question. Let $K/\mathbb{Q}_p$ be an extension of local fields. Then there is a unique prime $\mathfrak{p}$ in $K$. Corresponding to this prime we have the inertia degree $f$ and the ramification index $e$, and we have $p\mathcal{O}_{K}=\mathfrak{p}^e$ and $ef=[K:\mathbb{Q}_p]$. How can we find a global number field $L$, such that $L_v=K$ for some prime $v$ of $\mathcal{O}_L$.

Comment: Hi KcD can you help with the last part of my answer.

Comment: Briefly, you are looking for a number field $L$ that is dense in $K$, as the closure of $L$ will be $K$ and that also makes $K$ a completion of $L$. To find such $L$, write $K = \mathbf Q_p(\alpha)$ and let $f(x) \in \mathbf Q_p[x]$ be the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ over $\mathbf Q_p$. There are monic $g(x) \in \mathbf Q[x]$ with coefficients arbitrarily close to those of $f(x)$. For  $g(x)$ sufficiently close to $f(x)$, $g(x)$ has a root $\beta$ close to $\alpha$ and $K = \mathbf Q_p(\beta)$. The number field $L = \mathbf Q(\beta)$ answers your question.

Comment: For my previous comment, that way you show some root of $g(x)$ is close to $\alpha$ is with Krasner's lemma.  See the page https://mathoverflow.net/questions/239363/reference-for-every-local-field-can-be-realized-as-the-completion-of-a-global-f.

Answer (score 1):

For a finite Galois extension of $\Bbb Q$, its completions at different primes over $p$ are isomorphic to each other and are Galois over $\Bbb Q_p$, so they are all literally the same field inside an algebraic closure of $\Bbb Q_p$.
In terms of polynomials, if $K$ is the splitting field over $\Bbb{Q}$ of a polynomial in $\Bbb{Q}[x]$ then all the completions of $K$ at primes above $p$ are (isomorphic to) the splitting field of that same polynomial over $\Bbb{Q}_p$. In terms of decomposition groups, if $\mathfrak p$ is a prime over $p$ in a finite Galois extension  $K/\Bbb Q$ then ${\rm Gal}(K_\mathfrak p/\Bbb Q_p) \cong D(\mathfrak p|(p))$: there is a natural embedding $D(\mathfrak p|(p)) \to {\rm Gal}(K_\mathfrak p|\Bbb Q_p)$ that is surjective since both groups have the same size.

If $K/\Bbb{Q}$ is not Galois then it is more complicated to describe which primes over $p$ in $K$ have isomorphic completions. Let $L$ be the normal closure of $K/\Bbb{Q}$ and $L_p$ be "the" $p$-adic completion (the common completion of $L$ at an arbitrary prime over $p$ in $L$) and $f$ a choice of embedding $L\to L_p$.  The different subfields of $L$ that are isomorphic to $K$ are $\sigma(K)$ as $\sigma$ runs over ${\rm Gal}(L/\Bbb Q)$.

> The completions of $K$ at the different primes over $p$ in $\mathcal O_K$ are the fields $\overline{f(\sigma(K))}$ in $L_p$ as $\sigma$ runs over ${\rm Gal}(L/\Bbb{Q})$, where the overline means the closure in $L_p$, and the corresponding embedding $K\to \overline{f(\sigma(K))}$ induces a discrete valuation on $K$ and thus a (nonzero) prime of $\mathcal O_K$.

Let a completion $\overline{f(\sigma(K))}$ come from a prime $\mathfrak p$ over $p$ in $\mathcal O_K$:  $\overline{f(\sigma(K))} = K_\mathfrak p$. Let $\mathfrak P$ be a prime over $\mathfrak p$ in $\mathcal O_L$, so $\mathfrak p =\mathfrak P \cap \mathcal O_K$.

- For each $g\in {\rm Gal}(L_p/K_{\mathfrak p})=D(\mathfrak P|\mathfrak p)$ we have $\overline{f(\sigma(K))}=\overline{f(g\sigma(K))}$.
- If $g\in {\rm Gal}(L_p/\Bbb{Q}_p)=D(\mathfrak P|(p))$ then $\overline{f(\sigma(K))} \cong g (\overline{f(\sigma(K))}) =\overline{g(f(\sigma(K)))}=\overline{f(g\sigma(K))}$.
- Let $H=\{h\in {\rm Gal}(L/\Bbb{Q}), h(K)=K\}$. If $h\in H$ then $\overline{f(\sigma(K))} = \overline{f(\sigma h(K))}$.

My guess is that

$$\overline{f(\sigma(K))} \cong \overline{f(\sigma'(K))} \ \iff\ \sigma'\in D(\mathfrak P|(p)) \sigma H$$

Is it true ??

Comment: Suppose that $K$ is the splitting field of $f\in \Bbb{Q}[x]$, in other words $K/\mathbb{Q}$ is Galois, and let the ramification index and inertia degree of primes over $p$ be $e$ and $f'$. Let $K_{\mathfrak{p}}$ be the unique corresponding local field, the unique corresponding field to the primes $\mathfrak{p}_i$'s above $p$. Do we have these two relations? $p\mathcal{O}_{K}=\mathfrak{p}^e$? and $ef'=[K:\mathbb{Q}_p]$? What is the degree of $K/\mathbb{Q}_p$?

Comment: This is the point of the decomposition group $D(\mathfrak{p}/(p)) = \{ \sigma\in Gal(K/\Bbb{Q}),\sigma(\mathfrak{p})=\mathfrak{p}\}$, it is exactly $Gal(K_\mathfrak{p}/\Bbb{Q}_p)$ and it has $ef $ elements.

Comment: You asked me to look at your answer to address the end of it, but I found some of your notation extremely hard to read.  So before looking at the end I have made some edits to what you wrote. Please look it over and tell me if it still contains what you intended or if I created an error.

Comment: Seems fine, thank you.

Comment: Post the question you ask at the end as a separate self-contained question. A subtle issue that should be emphasized is that your $H$ is not ${\rm Gal}(L/K)$, but something potentially larger.  If we let $M = {\rm Gal}(L/K)$, so $M \subset H$, then the double cosets $D(\mathfrak P|(p))\sigma M$ as $\sigma$ runs over ${\rm Gal}(L/\mathbf Q)$ are in bijection with the primes over $p$ in $K$: $D(\mathfrak P|(p))\sigma M$ corresponds to $\mathfrak p_\sigma := \sigma^{-1}(\mathfrak P) \cap \mathcal O_K$.  The double cosets $D(\mathfrak P|(p))\sigma H$ are therefore a relation among (contd.)

Comment: the primes over $p$ in $K$ and it would be interesting if that relation really turns out to mean "isomorphic completions".

Comment: @KCd I will try again (maybe taking an example as I didn't even try with non-Galois cubic fields yet) and then post the question tomorrow